# What is the filterDispatcher in struts2

Tags: struts2

what is the work of Filter Dispatcher and StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter and where to use which filter? Actually I have created one app with filterdispatch and another with StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter so wanted to know the diffrence between these two or we can have both in same `web.xml`?

Comment: What version of Struts do you have?

Answer (score 3):

[`FilterDispatcher`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/FilterDispatcher.html) was the filter that was provided by Struts 2 for handling all request which needs to be controlled by struts framework. After `Struts 2.1.3` use of this filter was deprecated. As alternative [`StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.html), [`StrutsPrepareFilter`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareFilter.html) and [`StrutsExecuteFilter`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsExecuteFilter.html) any one of these three filters can be used. Use of first filter is suggested when there is no other filter in chain which requires action context information, such as [`Sitemesh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SiteMesh).

> what is the work of Filter Dispatcher and StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter and where to use which filter?

If you are using struts 2.1.3 or higher it is Advised to use newly available filters instead of deprecated filters. While googling came across following points on some blog

1. There were a lot of issued with the [`FilterDispatcher`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/FilterDispatcher.html) and its deployment.
2. New Filter provides a better way to enable customizations and overrides.
3. Make it crystal clear to developers what filters are doing what processes.
4. Make dispatch process be more flexible to support things like native operation in OSGi or plugin system.

> can have both in same web.xml?

Result this will be chaotic rather your application won't even be deployed. Doing this will be like asking two drivers to run a same car at a same time.